# Run java using custom JRE

Tags: batch-file, java

im trying to run my jar file using a .bat file with a custom bundled jre.

i dont know what should i write to bat file.

---

i found best solution:

`cd path\to\jre\bin`

java.exe -jar path-to-jar

Answer (score 5):

```
[PATH_TO_YOUR_JRE]\java[.exe|.bat] [OPTIONS] [CLASS] [ARGUMENTS]
```

Answer (score 3):

just qualify your version of java's path

normally you'd write

```
java -jar myjar.jar
```

here you'd write

```
c:\mybundle\bin\java -jar myjar.jar
```

Comment: Assuming your `myjar.jar` is in `c:\somepath\lib` and the java executable is in `c:\somepath\bin` you'd do `..\bin\java -jar myjar.jar`

Answer (score -3):

Is the bat in the same directory as the JRE distribution folder?

Have you tried `./myjre/bin/java.exe -jar myjar.jar`?

Comment: '.' i not reconized az internal or external command. this was error

Comment: At least have the decency to use the correct path separator. The question already hinted at Windows.

Comment: @Joey: The forward slash works on windows through `cmd` for me, and thus batch scripts. The `.` operator also works as expected, although it will throught hat error if you don't have a proper path constructed off the dot. Perhaps you need to be better at windows.\

Comment: The *command* may not use forward slashes as `cmd` uses it for options on its internal commands. Anything else that uses Windows APIs with paths may use a forward slash as well as a backslash, that's converted transparently. But you've caught *the one place* where it doesn't work*.